# I need a spacecraft to be pulled into the sun’s gravity!

Tags: internal-consistency, gravity

So, as I understand it, the spacecraft would need to move in the opposite direction to the orbit. Are there any calculations I could make to attach a clicking-tock onto this? If the spacecraft were travelling X kmh against its orbit at Y distance from the Sun, then it would take Z time to hit the Corona where at >5000ºC even tungsten/carbon composite materials would burn up. (The Parker Solar Probe will get to within 3.83 million miles to the sun, would that be a base calculation to help?)

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. As the name suggests, this community solves worldbuilding problems. This doesn't look like one. More info in the [help]. And quite aptly this same question was asked on Astronomy.SE https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33463

Comment: (1) What does "move in the opposite direction to the orbit" even mean? Any object in space moves on an orbit, unless powered by engines. (2) It is heap difficult to hit the Sun. Not impossible, but difficult. For a spacecraft leaving Earth orbit, a delta-v of 21 km/s is required to put the ship on an orbit which intersects the Sun, whereas, for example, to get to Mars low orbit it would need only about a delta-v of about 6.5 km/s. (3) Which is to say, a spacecraft leaving low Earth orbit needs quite a lot of oomph to hit the Sun, *and* careful aiming. (4) I second @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the Sun on purpose is very hard; doing it by accident is almost impossible.

The Earth has an orbital speed of about 30km/s. If you slow down below orbital speed, the Sun's gravity will pull you inward. However, that also causes you to speed up, which means you'll shoot *around* the Sun and enter an elliptical orbit, where you will remain until you eventually crash into one of the inner planets. You could apply thrust at an appropriate time to enter a circular orbit nearer the Sun, but the closer you want to get to the Sun, the more total thrust that will take.

It seems illogical if you aren't familiar with the orbital mechanics, but if you're already at/near orbital speed, it's actually far easier to fly *away* from the Sun (even to interstellar space) than toward it.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, elliptical orbit should be tight enough to go through Sun's corona, we don't need to hit Sun bulls-eye in the center.

Answer (score 0):

To free-fall into the Sun you need to have a very close to zero orbital velocity. Take this as an example:

Launched from Earth, you will need to lose the speed of Earth around the Sun to simply free fall dead center towards the center of the Sun. Maybe a little less to intercept the disk of the Sun on a collision orbit, but not much less: from 1 AU you may get close-but-no-cigar to the Sun, circle around and go back on a very elongated orbit.

The best moment to do it is from Earth's aphelion, when the speed is the lowest, namely [29.29 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit#Events_in_the_orbit) - so launch retrograde with the Earth movement with this speed and you are "at rest" in regards with the Sun and you'll free-fall.

Comment: Even then,  it takes a   metric shitton of energy to kill your orbital speed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the question doesn't ask "what's the energy required to do so". Otherwise, yes, it takes 420MJ/kg or thereabout to pull off the feat from Earth (which, I guess, makes it 420 metric shittons of energy for each kg of spacecraft)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Does it need to be metric?  Or would a standard shitton also work?